# Google Optimize Reports are not displaying conversions

Tags: optimization, reporting

I am currently running two a/b tests for two seperate landing pages through Google Optimize, and have been running these for about 5 days now (started April 5th). To date, i have not been able to see any conversions when i check the 'reporting' tab for either of these experiments. It is tracking sessions however.

I have created segments in Analytics per their variant IDs and have been able to see that there are indeed conversions that have resulted from traffic passing through the experiments - but this is not showing up in the Optimize reports.

I set up three objectives for both experiments, all of which were Google Analytics goals that fire when a user reaches a goal destination URL. All of these are on the same domain that the experiment is running (so no cross domain tracking needed here).

I would expect that if analytics is showing conversions, then Optimize should also be displaying these in their reports - yet this isn't the case.

If anyone has any insight, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you found solution?